# Determining the type of RAM

Tags: hardware, ram, system-info

I'm trying to determine what type of RAM a computer has (whether it's DDR2 or DDR3).

I've tried several commands:

- `sudo lshw -short -C memory` outputs this:

  ```
  H/W path        Device      Class       Description
  ===================================================
  /0/2                        memory      1980MiB System memory
  ```
- `sudo dmidecode -t memory` outputs this:

  ```
  # dmidecode 2.12
  # No SMBIOS nor DMI entry point found, sorry.
  ```
- `sudo dmidecode | grep -A 15 Memory` outputs nothing.
- I also tried looking in `hardinfo` under "Devices>Memory" but I can't find out the type.

**Edit:**

- `sudo lshw -C memory` outputs this only:

  ```
  *-memory                
       description: System memory
       physical id: 2
       size: 1980MiB
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo lshw -c memory` without the `-short` option.

Here's an example output:

```
$ sudo lshw -c memory
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          product: ACR16D3LS1KNG/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 16392411
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     [...shortened output...]
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       [...shortened output...]
```

You see the RAM type in the `description` field of every memory bank, like here:

```
description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
```

Comment: Edited the question. thx 4 effort